# Stuff not included in RailsReady?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to install RoR on Ubuntu 12.0.4 using RailsReady(https://github.com/joshfng/railsready).  Afterwards I restarted my computer and while typing `ruby -v` works, typing `rails -v` returns `unrecognized`, as does `mysql` in the terminal.  What do I have to do to be able to launch rails and mysql?  Do I have to install them individually using sudo even though I've already installed RailsReady?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the README and the script itself shows that it gets you *ready* to install Rails by installing typical packages needed in order to create a Rails-based development environment, and then attempts to install it.

Per @madth3's comment below, lines 176 to 182 of railsready.sh does attempt to install Rails, so look for any error messages when you run that script.

MySQL appears to require separate installation using standard methods appropriate for your system.

Comment: This line `gem install bundler passenger rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` should install Rails.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that; was just looking in the ubuntu recipe for the OP. It still doesn't seem to explicitly install MySQL.

Comment: did you resolve this yet? i fired off about 5 commands yesterday to get it all setup and can look back at my browser history to see